# Printing from Linux to HP P4515x Mailbox

Tags: centos, centos5, hp, printing

I need to be able to print from my CentOS 5 server to our HP P4515x printer mailbox (output bin/stacker). I am already able to print as normal from the server to the printer but I cannot figure out how to get the paper to print to the stacker.

I have installed WebMin and added the printer through there and it's using the "HP LaserJet Series PCL 6" CUPS driver.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What printing subsystem are you using (hint: its probably cups)? Have you installed the [hp4515 ppd file](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/bsc-413/196753/1/p4010.txt)?

I'd be surprised if Webmin provides the level of access required for configuring stuff like this - it's not that sophisticated a tool - try using the tools provided for your printing system.

Note that while most printing systems (including cups) will allow you to configure a default output bin/collation, usually these settings will be overridden by the client - i.e. you need to use a HP4515x driver on the machine which is creating the print jobs (if that's something other than the centos box).

Comment: I'm using CUPS but couldn't find the PPD for my printer anywhere and HP support were totally useless - thank you!! There's no other system printint to the CentOS server, it's just CentOS sending the print jobs via the lpr command direct to the printer. That part is working but it's just the output bin I couldn't figure out.

Should I just replace the PPD that's already on the server under /etc/cups/ppd/? Do you know how I can get it to print to a specific output-bin?

Comment: Sorted! I copied the PPD into /etc/cups/ppd/ and used the following command to print to a specific output-bin:`lpr -P <printer> -o OutputBin=Bin2 "file.txt"`